# core image custom kernel not working

Tags: ios, glsl, cikernel

I am stuck on a very weird issue.
I have the following very simple kernel, but everytime I run it, I get the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error.

```
kernel vec4 test (sampler source_image)  
{  
vec2 a = vec2(100.0, 200.0);  
vec4 pixValue = sample(source_image, a);  
return pixValue;  
}
```

If I add samplerTransform, I still get the same error.

```
kernel vec4 test (sampler source_image)  
{  
vec2 a = vec2(100.0, 200.0);  
vec4 pixValue = sample(source_image, samplerTransform(source_image, a));  
return pixValue;  
}
```

However, if I change the kernel to the following, everything works fine and I get returned the source image. This goes to show that the rest of my objective-c code is working just fine. So the issue must be in the kernel codes in the above samples somewhere.

```
kernel vec4 test (sampler source_image)  
{  
vec2 a = vec2(100.0, 200.0);  
vec4 pixValue = sample(source_image, samplerCoord(source_image));  
return pixValue;  
}
```

Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: My usage of `samplerTransform` is with an *offset* of `samplerCoord`. And to be honest, that's all I've ever seen. My best guess is that a simple `vec2` won't work. Be it because of ROI (region of interest) or something else.